# is this callback structured correctly?

Tags: javascript, callback

I want to save all sections, made updates to questions with IDs for the just saved sections, then save the questions, and then if that is successful fire a function nextPage that redirects the page. I'm trying to confirm this is correct. It seems to act funny if I don't have the anonymous function wrapped around saveAllQuestions.

```
saveAllSections(function () {saveAllQuestions(nextPage)});
```

**Update:**

On the success of saveAllSections it does the following:

```
if (typeof(callback) == 'function')
               callback();
```

On the success of saveAllQuestions it does the following:

```
            if (questionValuesToSave.length>0) {
                saveAllQuestionValues(questionValuesToSave, callback);
            }
            else {
                 // once its done hide AJAX saving modal
                hideModal();
                if (typeof(callback) == 'function')
                    callback();
            }
```

On the success of saveAllQuestionValues (assuming there are some) it does the following:

```
                    if (typeof(callback) == 'function')
                        callback();
```

Comment: It looks like it could be correct, but we would need to see code for `saveAllSections` and `saveAllQuestions` to really be able to say more.

Comment: define 'funny'?  if `saveAllSections()` is expecting a function as an argument, then `saveAllQuestions(nextPage)` should work just fine

Comment: @sircapsalot no it won't, it will execute that code and then pass the result.

Comment: Where is `nextPage` coming from?

Comment: nextPage is a function thats just a window.top.location=URL;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is a generally correct syntax for a callback, though its hard to know for sure without seeing more code.

The following code

```
saveAllSections(saveAllQuestions(nextPage));
```

would fail because `saveAllQuestions(nextPage)` is the syntax to execute a function, rather than define it.  So it will execute that immediately and pass the result to `saveAllSections`, which will try to use it as the callback.  Since this is likely not a function, and almost definitely not the function you want to pass you will get strange behavior, most likely an error.

Wrapping this in an anonymous function means that you're passing a function to `saveAllSections`, which does not execute until it is called by the outer function or as a callback.

#### UPDATE:

Looks like saveAllQuestions is also async based on your description, so executing it immediately will definitely not work correctly.  The anonymous function wrapper is a completely acceptable solution if you need to pass a param.

If you didn't, you could just use

```
saveAllSections(saveAllQuestions)
```

Comment: Whoever is downvoting this should add an explanation.

Comment: I would appreciate that too.  It may be out of date now that the OP has added code, still sorting through that, but I have no idea why I'm being downvoted.: *Edit:* After looking through the code, I'm standing by this answer.  Could somebody please explain the downvotes?

Comment: I didnt downvote, thats kinda what I assumed was happening and was looking for confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, you can pass a function as an argument.  This allows for simpler code and asynchronous callbacks.  In your attempt, you don't pass a function in.  You *execute* a function, so the result of `saveAllQuestions(nextPage)` is passed into the function, not the function `saveAllQuestions`.

Hopefully this example helps.

```
function add(a,b) {
    return a+b;
}

function mul(a,b) {
    return a*b;
}

function doMath(num1, num2, op) {
    return op(num1, num2);
}

document.write( doMath(4,5, add) ); // 9
document.write( doMath(4,5, function (n1,n2) {return n1+n2;}) ); // 9
document.write( doMath(2,5, mul) ); // 10
document.write( doMath(2,5, function (n1,n2) {return n1*n2;}) ); // 10
document.write( doMath( doMath(1,3, add) , 4, mul) ); // 16
```

Comment: This example makes my head hurt, might take some time to digest but thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need to wrap `saveAllQuestions` in an anonymous function is because otherwise `saveAllQuestions` gets executed right away, and its return value gets passed as the callback to `saveAllSections`.

If you wrap `saveAllQuestions` in an anonymous function, you prevent `saveAllQuestions` from executing right away.